# PHP CURL giving 502 ERROR suddently. Server side all configurations checked and all are good

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am having 2 domains and name of each domain are: 1) a.com 2) b.com both this domain hosted on same server so all configurations are same as well.

Now, Main issue I am getting at this time is if I execute CURL with domain: a.com (with curl url like: a.com/curltesting.php) then its failing with 502 error. But if I execute CURL with b.com (with curl url like: b.com/curltesting.php) then its working well.

Now if I execute CURL with b.com (with curl url like: a.com/curltesting.php) then also failing. Because anything in "a.com" is failing to execute from any place.

I have tried to use all possible ways in CURL and made sure that all extentions etc working well, ip etc also not blocked so all settings are fine.

And this issue arised sudden from no where. So no changes happend but still this issue arised.

Here is code which I used (Code is working well but for other domain in same server. for 1 omain its not working but for other working):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.b.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) 
$response = curl_error($ch);

echo stripslashes($response);
curl_close($ch);
```

Please help! Thanks.

I have explained full details of what I an facing issue with and what things I tried.

Comment: have you tried executing `a.com/curltesting.php` independently. Is it working as expected?

Comment: Yes its not working. only for specific domain its not working while in other domain in same server working.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. cURL might give more insight on what's going wrong. You can use `curl -v https://www.b.com` from CLI, or `curl --head https://www.b.com` to only get the request header. Any clues there?

Comment: The problem is not with the code you posted.
Apparently, the problem is communication between the problem host and some other point upstream.


502 - The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.

Comment: thanks for responses and help. Its fixed now. It was mainly sounds because of firewall.